# BottomNavigationBar with custom highlight graphics

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

Our designer gave me this sketch of a bottom navigation bar.

[image]

The circle below the first item indicates that it is selected. How should one implement this highlighting mechanism? Is it possible to use selectors for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a drawable for the selected state and the non selected state where the selected state contains the dot. Then just change the source image when selected.